# Не срабатывают CSS свойства .container

Tags: css

Создала в файле *index.html* контейнер:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

В CSS файле прописала для него свойства:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Но, заголовок *Hello, world!* не сдвинулся с места. Хотя, в рамках контейнера, у него должен появиться отступ слева, т.к. контейнер центрирован. Надпись осталась на месте, как если бы она была сама по себе, не в контейнере.

Файл CSS точно подключен, проверяла - меняла *background-color* всего *body*, менялся. Шрифт и его размер тоже меняются, значит, проблема не в подключении самого CSS.

В чём может быть проблема? Почему заголовок не изменил положение?

Comment: Проверил у себя, работает. Может... разрешение экрана маленькое или браузер своеобразный

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял, то Вам нужно центрировать заголовок. Запустите пример ниже и давайте разберёмся:

```css
*    { box-sizing: border-box;  }
html { border: 3px solid blue;  }
body { border: 3px solid green; }
div  { border: 3px solid gold;  }
h1   { border: 3px solid red;   }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Все представленные элементы в HTML-разметке - блочные, т.е. они по умолчанию растягиваются занимая всю доступную ширину.

В примере мы видим, что все элементы растянулись по-максимуму. Именно поэтому, при небольшой ширине страницы не видно, как отрабатывает `margin: 0 auto;`. При ширине страницы больше, чем `max-width: 1200px;`, всё работает, как положено.

Таким образом, становится, ясно почему не центрируется `.container` - это блочный элемент, он распирается максимально (`width: 100%;`), отступы пропадают, а следовательно не к чему применять `margin: 0 auto;`. Вариант решения - задать фиксированную ширину, но нам нужно не это.

Чтобы центрировать заголовок, достаточно добавить выравнивание текста в самом теге заголовка `h1`:

```css
*    { box-sizing: border-box;  }
html { border: 3px solid blue;  }
body { border: 3px solid green; }
div  { border: 3px solid gold;  }
h1   { border: 3px solid red;   }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за развернутый ответ! Оказалось, проблема действительно в маленьком мониторе, и контейнер растягивался так, что результата не было видно. При смене максимальной ширины с 1200 на 1000 стало ясно, что код работает, так что просто надо его адаптировать работой с самим заголовком или другими способами. Главное, теперь ясна причина. Благодарю!